# Ajax HtmlEditorExtender - Insert image pops up login box

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, access-control

I have an Intranet web site that uses Windows Authentication, so users already logged in are not ask for credentials when accessing the site. I added an Ajax HTML editor extender with "Insert Image" tool but some users who can access the site with no issues (no login dialog) are presented with the login when they click on Insert Image icon.

I checked folder security and I have <servername>\IIS_IUSRS, <servername>\USERS, Network Services (under which application pool runs) with full control. I did this for inetpub\wwwroot and all sub-folders, but still asks users for credentials.

Not sure what I am missing. I tried searching for this but none of extender issues I found deals with image file access issue.

**Update**

I changed the tags for this post from ajax control toolkit to IIS (maybe that was the reason for downvote, i don't know). I noticed that if I add the user's domain ID to <servername>/Administrators group (from Server Manager - Local Users and groups) on the server, then he can add images.

Extremely ridiculous solution but wanted to know how I can get him to insert images into editor.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the application pool I was using for the web site (call it, MyAppPool) had as one of its properties "Load User Profile" set to true. This causes a folder be created in C:\Users folder called "MyAppPool" to which Network Service (under which application pool was running) had no access; hence the login prompt popping up.

Two solutions: give Network Service access to this folder or set Load User Profile to false, which is what I did and it solved my issue.

Hopefully this helps someone running into the same issue and save him/her some grief.